# How to define stroke around background rectangle of textblock in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, text, layout

I would like to have some text to be inside a rectangle with stroke around this rectangle (just like property "Stroke" of the object "Rectangle" itself). But I didn't manage to find a property of the object "Textblock" which defines such a stroke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place the `TextBlock` inside a `Border` and set the properties of the `Border` to draw the rectangle around your text.

Answer (score 0):

Every `TextBlock` element contains one or more child `Inline` elements. There is a type of Inline (`InlineUIContainer`) that supports hosting a UIElement: basically, this means you can host arbitrary UI elements within a TextBlock. Flipping [@GraemeF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1854727/4265041) on its head, you can host a `Border` element *inside* the TextBlock, like so:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Padding="20">
        <Run>Hello</Run>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="4" Margin="0,0,0,-11">
                <TextBlock Text="Boxed" />
            </Border>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        <Run>World</Run>
    </TextBlock>

</Window>
```

This will look something like this:

[image: Bordered text within a TextBlock]

You will have to experiment with the Margin on the Border element in order to get the text baselines to match up, but other than that the technique seems to work well.